# Yii dropdown with AJAX not working as expected

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have the following view named `'findreseller.php'`:

```
<?php

$countries = CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');

echo CHtml::dropdownlist('find_reseller', '', $countries,
    array('ajax'=>array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->getController()->createAbsoluteUrl('/webcare/reseller/loadAjaxData'),
            'update' =>'#data',
            )
         )
    );

?>
<div id="data">
   <?php $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider))?>
</div>
```

_ajaxContent just echoes the result, nothing special there...
The dropdown, as you can see is generated with CHtml because I dont't need a form. I just need an onChange event to do something...

As per the code that follows, in `'/webcare/reseller/loadAjaxData'` I have:

```
public function actionLoadAjaxData() {
    $country = $_POST['find_reseller'];
    //do something...
    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($country_reseller);

    $this->render('findreseller', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
}
```

I can tell that I am missing something, but I am not sure what exactly.

### Edit

Modified like this:

```
 <?php
 //CHtml::form();
 $countries = CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');

 echo CHtml::dropdownlist('find_reseller', '', $countries,
    array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', //request type
            'url'=>CController::createUrl('/webcare/reseller/loadAjaxData'), //url to call.
            //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
            'update'=>'#city_id', //selector to update
            'data'=>'js: $(this).val()', 
            //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
        )
    )
 ); 

 //empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
 echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array());
 //CHtml::endForm();
 ?>
 <div id="data">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider))?>
 </div>
```

And now I get:

http://prntscr.com/42wwx6

And I have the following controller action:

```
 public function actionLoadAjaxData() {
    $country = $_POST['country_id'];
    ...
    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($country_reseller);

    $data = User::model()->findAll('country_id=:country_id AND reseller=:reseller', 
              array(':country_id'=>(int) $_POST['country_id'], ':reseller'=>1));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'city','city');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }

    $this->render('action_name', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
}
```

### Edit 2

If I write a die in actionLoadAjaxData(), right at the beginning, the method is loaded fine, the action is ok and the server answers 200.

Comment: is the ajax request sent? (you can observe it with firebug for example)

Comment: nope... nothing is send in Network :(

Comment: Check L.E. ... now I get 500 Internal Server Error :(